# What exactly does the 3-operand imul instruction do in ia-32 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, instruction-set, instructions, opcode

I'm reading the instruction

```
imul 0xffffffd4(%ebp, %ebx, 4), %eax
```

and I'm baffled by what it's doing exactly. I understand that `imul` multiplies, but I can't figure out the syntax.

Comment: There is a 3-operand form of `imul`, but only with an immediate source.  (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/imul).  Like AT&T `imul $123, (mem), %ecx`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hooray for AT&T assembly base/index syntax!  It's not a 3-operand multiply at all.  It's the same 2-operand one you know and love, it's just that the first one is a bit complicated.  It means:

```
%ebp + (4 * %ebx) + 0xffffffd4
```

Or:

```
%ebp + (4 * %ebx) - 44
```

To be a bit clearer (and in base 10).  The AT&T base/index syntax breaks down as:

```
offset(base, index, multiplier)
```

Comment: +1, and the instruction is multiplying the value in `eax` by (probably) an integer in a local array.

Answer (score 19):

(I know and prefer Intel/MASM syntax, so I will use that. Note that the order of operands is reversed in AT&T.)

Your instruction is actually a two-operand `imul`, which in Intel syntax is:

```
imul eax, DWORD PTR [ebp + ebx*4 + 0FFFFFFD4h]
```

Where `eax` is the destination operand and the memory location is the source operand. The two-operand `imul` performs a multiplication of the source and destination operands and stores the result in the destination.  Unlike 1-operand, it doesn't write a high half anywhere, so the same instruction works for signed and unsigned, like with `add` and left shift.

This instruction is multiplying a register by the integer in an array. Most likely this appears in a loop and the array is a local variable (on the stack starting at `ebp-44`).

---

The three-operand `imul` instruction is:

```
imul dest, source1, immediate
imul reg,  r/m,   imm           ; showing what kind of operand is allowed
```

The `source1` operand (either a memory location or a register) is multiplied by the `immediate` operand (either an 8-bit or 16/32-bit constant) and the result is stored in the `dest` operand (a 16, 32 or 64-bit register).

See Intel's manual entry for `imul`: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/imul

Comment: (I've answered both questions for people who get here by searching by title.)